# Migration from `partitioned` gem to `pg_party`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, partitioning

Good day.

Does anybody know how to migrate from [partitioned gem](https://github.com/fiksu/partitioned) to [pg_party gem](https://github.com/rkrage/pg_party)?
We have a super old project and try to update.

The `partitioned` gem uses other schema for partitioned tables, e.g.:

- table `p201511`, schemaname: `my_table_name_partitions`
- table `my_table_name`, schemaname: `public`

Second, the `partitioned` gem doesn't use native PG table partitioning :(

We use partitioning by date.

Link to question in GitHub: https://github.com/rkrage/pg_party/issues/69

Thanks!

I investigated how `partitioned` gem works and reviewed the https://github.com/rkrage/pg_party docs.